# Solve the differential equation $y'''=x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve $y'''=x$.
I integrated it and I got
$$y''=x^2/2+c_1$$

Integrating again
$$y'=x^3/12+c_2$$

Integrating for the third time
$$y=x^4/48+c_3$$

but the answer on my book is $y=x^2/24+c_1 \cdot x^2/2+c_2 \cdot x+c_3$... where am I wrong?

Comment: Check your second integration.

Comment: To add to comment by copper.hat, the second integration has $2$ mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be

$$
y''=\frac{x^2}{2}+c_1
$$

$$
y'=\frac{x^3}{6}+xc_1+c_2
$$

$$
y=\frac{x^4}{24}+\frac{x^2c_1}{2}+xc_2+c_3
$$

Answer (score 1):

You should know that $\displaystyle \int ndx=nx$ where $n$ is a constant.

Your first step was correct when you got

$y''=\dfrac{x^2}{2}+C_1$

But when you integrate that you should get

$y'=\dfrac{x^3}{2\times 3}+C_1x+C_2$

And likewise for the third step you should get again by integrating

$y=\dfrac{x^4}{2\times 3\times 4}+\dfrac{C_1x^2}{2}+C_2x+C_3$

Answer (score 1):

When we integrate a function $f$, we find a differentiable function $F$ such that $F'=f$. However, if $F$ is an antiderivative, then it is easy to see that $F+C$ is also an antiderivative for every constant $C$. Hence we should obtain a constant of integration every time we integrate.

In your case, we want to integrate the function $y'''=x$ three times. First time we get

$$y''=\frac{x^2}{2}+C_1.$$

Second time we get

$$y'=\frac{x^3}{6}+C_1x+C_2.$$

Third time we get

$$y=\frac{x^4}{24}+C_1\frac{x^2}{2}+C_2x+C_3.$$

Observe the power of $x$ in the first term.